# Does $\pi$ contain infinitely many "zeros" in its decimal expansion?

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, decimal-expansion

Some number doesn't contain $"7"$ in its decimal expansion.

For example Liouville's constant

$$L=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{10^{n!}}=0.11000100....$$

contains only $0$ and $1$.

It is well-known that if number is "normal" it contain infinite number of  $\lbrace0,1,2...9\rbrace$. 
In other words, if $\pi$ is 10-normal, then the limiting frequency of "7" (or any other single digit) in its decimal expansion is $\frac{1}{10}.$

It is not known that $\pi$ is normal, but can we say that $\pi$ (or $\sqrt{2}$) has infinitely many 0 or any other single digit in its decimal expansion?  If "no", how many zeros contains $pi$?

Also it is easy to prove that  Champernowne number $0.1234567891011...$ contain infinite many "zeros" without know that it is 10-normal.

Comment: As we currently can't say whether or not $\pi$ is normal, I doubt that anyone can answer this question about how many zeros there are in its decimal expansion.

Comment: I am not sure about the decimal expansion, but in the binary expansion, if it contains finitely many $0$'s then at some point it must be all ones, and will not be irrational.

Comment: We can at least say that at least two digits must occur infinitely often. (Otherwise $\pi$ would be rational) However, for any given digit $d$, I think that it is an open problem whether $d$ occurs infinitely often in the decimal expansion of $\pi$.