# Decimal expansions of irrational numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi, decimal-expansion

I have the following question (I am not a mathematician, so I am sorry if it is ill-formed!).

Some irrational numbers such as $\pi$ are suspected to be normal in that any finite string of digits is 'equally likely' to appear in their decimal expansion. As I understand it, it is an open question whether $\pi$ is normal.

Are there any irrational numbers of which we cannot know whether they are normal, so that the only way to check whether such a number has infinitely many zeros, for example, would be to 'go through' all of its decimal expansion?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties_and_examples

Comment: Compare also with other posts here, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311846/does-pi-contain-infinitely-many-zeros-in-its-decimal-expansion). It is never clear if something is "the only way to check". Perhaps we have a new idea one day.

Comment: @BarryCipra Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: "*... of which we* **cannot** *know whether...*"  Times change and it is difficult to speak in absolutes.  We might not be able to *now* but a hundred years more into the future perhaps new techniques will have been developed.

Comment: Note that being normal is a MUCH stronger condition than simply knowing there are infinitely many occurrences of every digit. For instance, being normal implies that as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ the proportion of digits that equal $0,$ $1, \ldots,$ $9$ each approaches $10\%.$ However, we will still have infinitely many occurrences of every digit if those proportions, instead, approach $6\%,$ $24\%,$ $3\%,$ etc. (arrange for all $10$ percents to add to $100\%).$ Some of the proportions could be very small, such as $0.007\%,$ while others could be very close to $100\%.$ **(continued)**

Comment: In fact, the proportion of a digit can be exactly $0\%$ while still having infinitely many occurrences (e.g. have the digit $7$ at the $4$'th, $9$'th, $16$'th, $\ldots,$ $45^2$'th, $46^2$'th, $\ldots$ locations, and digits different from $7$ at the other locations); also, the limiting proportions for a given digit might not exist (i.e. as $n$ gets larger and larger, the proportions oscillate rather than converge). Interestingly, as a huge contrast for the situation regarding "most" in the sense of Lebesgue measure, **(continued)**

Comment: for "most" numbers in the Baire category sense, each digit occurs infinitely often AND, as $n \rightarrow \infty,$ the proportion of each digit varies throughout the interval $[0\%,\,100\%] = [0,1]$ so erratically ("so uniformly" is probably a better description) that every number in $[0,1]$ is a subsequent limit of the sequence of proportions for that digit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the concept of countable and uncountable sets?  In particular that the real numbers are uncountable?  If not then see [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

The rational numbers are countable and hence a strict subset of the reals.  There are other interesting sets which are intuitively larger yet still countable.

The [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) include $\sqrt 2$ and other numbers constructed with roots but more generally any number which is the solution to a polynomial with integer coefficients.

The [computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) are those for which we have an algorithm to compute them to any desired precision.  Note that this just means computable in a theoretical sense not any practical one.  $\pi$ and $e$ are examples.  We can in principle compute the googolth ($10^{100}$) digit of $\pi$.  It is highly unlikely that we ever will as a googol is way more than the number of atoms in the visible universe.  Although intuitively bigger again, this set is still countable hence some real numbers must not be computable.

These uncomputable numbers might be what you are looking for.  There is no algorithm  for their digits, they could only be specified by writing them out.

Can we give an example of any?  Well sort of.  We can look at an even larger set: the [definable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number).  A definable number has a definition which is in a sense exact but cannot be computed.  Maybe the closest to a concrete example of a definable but uncomputable number is [Chaitin's  Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant).  This set is still countable so there are real numbers which are not even definable.  If a merely non-computable number did not satisfy  your requirements then maybe a non-definable one does.

Comment: Another good example for a noncomputable number is the inverse sum of busy beaver numbers